# Excel: Reading the column and row number from the cell with a link to the target cell

Tags: microsoft-excel

Let me give an example.

I have a cell e.g. `A1` and 2 more cells  e.g `B2` and `C3`.

In `B2` I write *"=A1"*, what I want now to make in cell `C3` is to write either the column and row number of the cell `A1` but from the link of the cell `B2`.

How is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

Column number:

```
=COLUMN(INDIRECT(MID(FORMULATEXT(B2),2,1000)))
```

Row number:

```
=ROW(INDIRECT(MID(FORMULATEXT(B2),2,1000)))
```